# Adding dom elements relative to input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function which add elements to the dom according to the value inserted into an input element, and if i insert new value in to the input the previous elements are erased and new elements are inserted.

what i want is to keep the old elements and add new ones to it

html:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="insert the number of div" class="number">
<button>submit</button>
<br>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$('button').click(function(){
        var boxes = '';
        var i;
        var inputValue = $('.number').val();
        for(i=0; i < inputValue; i++){
            boxes += "<div class='box'></div>";
        }
        $('#wrapper').html(boxes);
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of $.html

```
$('#wrapper').html(boxes);
```

Use

```
$('#wrapper').append(boxes);
```

You can read more about both methods here:

- [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
- [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)